# How to change datatable column name

Tags: c#, datatable

Hi i like to change data table column name to upper case (first latter) so i tried below code

e.g

i need to convert like below

```
name into Name
```

Code

```
foreach (DataColumn column in obj_dt.Columns)
  column.ColumnName = column.ColumnName.ToUpper();
```

but its converting full name into upper case i need to convert only first latter only ...
how i can do it...
thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In The [CultureInfo.TextInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.textinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class you have many methods that deal with the culture specific casing rules. The method that are looking for is: [ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
TextInfo ti = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
foreach (DataColumn column in obj_dt.Columns)
   column.ColumnName = ti.ToTitleCase(column.ColumnName);
```

You need to add the `using System.Globalization;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in obj_dt.Columns)
  column.ColumnName = column.ColumnName[0].ToUpper()+column.ColumnName.Substring(1);
```

This way you only make the first letter of you column's name uppercase and then you concatenate it with the rest of your initial name -all the chars except from the first one.

Comment: I suppose that column.ColumName is a string. Since you were using ToUpper on it and you didn't get any error that's reasonable. Then using column.ColumnName[0] you get the first character of your string. Last, a character has a method called ToUpper, which does what it's name. So I can't get why it didn't work. What's the error?

Comment: No overload  Method for "ToUpper()" takes 0 arguments